# How can I get a List<int> from LINQ to XML that produces List<List<int>>?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML snippet as follows:

```
<PerformancePanel>
    <LegalText>
        <Line id="300" />
        <Line id="304" />
        <Line id="278" />
    </LegalText>
</PerformancePanel>
```

I'm using the following code to get an object:

```
var performancePanels = new
{
    Panels = (from panel in doc.Elements("PerformancePanel")
              select new
              {
                  LegalTextIds = (from legalText in panel.Elements("LegalText").Elements("Line")
                                  select new List<int>()
                                  {
                                      (int)legalText.Attribute("id")
                                  }).ToList()
               }).ToList()
};
```

The type of `LegalTextIds` is `List<List<int>>`. How can I get this as a `List<int>?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create a new list for each item, just make one list:

```
LegalTextIds = (from legalText in panel.Elements("LegalText").Elements("Line")
                select (int)legalText.Attribute("id")).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=VS.90).aspx)  extension method:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>()
    { 
        new List<int>(){1, 2},
        new List<int>(){3, 4}
    };

var result = lists.SelectMany(x => x);  // results in 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Or, for your specific case:

```
var performancePanels = new
{
    Panels = (from panel in doc.Elements("PerformancePanel")
            select new
            {
                LegalTextIds = (from legalText in panel.Elements("LegalText").Elements("Line")
                             select new List<int>()
                             {
                                 (int)legalText.Attribute("id")
                             }).SelectMany(x => x)
            }).ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
List<int> GenListOfIntegers = 
          (from panel in doc.Elements("PerformancePanel").Elements("Line")
              select int.Parse(panel.Attribute("id").Value)).ToList<int>();
```